# Generate link_to without path (only anchor)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to have path like "#privacy" for tab plugin. Link must contain only anchor. When I use `link_to 'Privacy', :anchor => 'privacy'` Rails generate `/privacy#privacy` - link, that contains full path and anchor.

How can I told Rails to generate url without path (only anchor)?

Thanks.

**Solved**: `link_to 'Privacy', '#privacy'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will create a link the way you want -

```
link_to "my-privacy", "#privacy"
```

In most browsers, the path of the current page will be prefixed, but if you check the source of the  page, the following html will be seen -

```
<a href="#privacy">my-privacy</a>
```

This will most probably serve your purpose for the UI, just that you'll have to split the url at '#' using Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you
    <%= link_to "title", resource_path(:anchor => "anchor") %>

Answer (score 0):

No generation of routes is needed also no generator is needed.

```
<%= link_to "link text", "#", :id => 'your_id_here' %>
```

You will need the id to access the object via jQuery.

//edit

```
<%= link_to "link text", "/#anchor", :id => 'your_id_here' %>
```

Comment: I dont want to access element. I need to have link like `#anchor`

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it. Correct is without slash. But thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for this exact scenario is to just use `<%= link_to "link text", "#anchor" %>`. The anchor tag is used within `url_for` and doesn't really give you a clean way to just use an anchor.