# Rails - Link to Div on current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I link to a div on the current page.

For example, I have

```
<%= link_to "Comments", :anchor => "comments_div" %>
```

which links to `www.url.com/#comments_div`.

How can I link to a div from the current page, including params in the url, eg: `www.url.com/r?utf8=✓&page_id=1232&lod_in=f#comments_div`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate link\_to without path (only anchor)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461903/generate-link-to-without-path-only-anchor)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<%= link_to "Comments", "#{request.original_url}#comments_div" %>
```

Reference: [request.original_url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url)

Comment: Wouldn't this result in a new request when clicked on?

Answer (score 1):

You can link to the div on the current page like so:

`<%= link_to "Comments", "#comments_div" %>`

No need to submit a new request.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply do an a tag with the div name of the div you want to jump to

`<a href="#Comments">Comments</a>"`

Then you'd have your div down bellow:

`<h1 id="Comments">Comments</h1>`